# "sh runMyCode.sh" not loops in format "for n in {10..99}"

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, centos

I am so newbie to bash scripting so I am missing something but can't even imagine what is missing. Previously below script run well on `CentOS 5` but recently I have switched to `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and the loop started not to work as expected. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {10..99}
do
if !  ps aux | grep "ABC$n DEF " | grep -v grep
then
   echo "Activating ABC$n DEF "
fi
done
```

If I run the script as `./runMyScript.sh` it activates from 10 to 99 just as expected:

```
Activating ABC10 DEF 
Activating ABC11 DEF 
Activating ABC12 DEF 
...
Activating ABC99 DEF
```

However if I run the code as `sh runMyScript.sh` it does not loops and it activates single element, printing `Activating ABC{10..99}DEF` only.
the script file is also executable for both method as `-rwxr-xr-x`.

I don't know if it is just normal, because two methods work like charm on platform `CentOS 5`. I am aware that `./`runs on `bash`and `sh`runs on shell, but then what does work on CentOS and what does not on Ubuntu? What might I do so that both platforms, both methods act same?

Comment: running it with `bash script` will have the same effect on everywhere..

Comment: @Jahid just because script runs on `bash` on everywhere. Just like `./script.sh`works everywhere because script starts with `#!/bin/bash` right?

Comment: In the past, many Linux distributions had /bin/sh as a link to the bash binary /bin/bash.  But some systems are moving away from that, and on these platforms /bin/sh is a completely different shell (dash, ash, pdksh, or the original Bourne shell), and using bash syntax may not give the desired result.

Comment: yeah, that's right. ./script will work everywhere too as long as you got the shebang correct

Comment: Naming bash scripts with `.sh` extensions is bad form in part because it implies -- incorrectly -- that they can be run with `sh`. Don't use extensions at all for your scripts; you don't run `ls.elf`.

Comment: The code posted will not produce the given output. As-is, it will print `ABC` followed by the contents of the variable `$nDEF` (which will likely be empty) - not the contents of the variable `$n` followed by `DEF`. Do `ABC${n}DEF" instead.

Comment: @AndrewMedico the original code is more like `ABC$n `. `$n` is followed by a space, so I missed that too while shortening the code. Thanks for the info tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sh` is `dash` on Ubuntu and it doesn't understand the looping sequence `{10..99}`. So it loops once interpreting the whole `{10..99}` as one string. I believe the default `sh` is bash or ksh on CentOS. So it works.

Always use `./script.sh` if you have proper shebang or use `[bash|ksh|whatever] script.sh` if you have code written for specific shell. Using a different interpreter than the code is written for is not always going to work. Even if it does on occasions, it's dangerous as one shell's construct may not be available or have same semantics.